# In Rust, why `std::any::TypeId::of` is not `const fn`?

Tags: rust

An obviously question:

Why `std::any::TypeId::of::<T>` isn't a `const fn`?

<del>Since `std::any::type_name::<T>` is already a `const fn`, I can't find any reason.</del>

Comment: There is no `type_of` so I don't really know what you're referring to. Are you thinking of [type_name](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/fn.type_name.html)? But it's not const either. And for `TypeId::of`, [have you considered looking at the tracking issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/77125)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at [the code](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/any.rs.html#439-441) (click the [src] button to the right of [its documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/struct.TypeId.html#method.of)), you can see that `of` *is* marked `const`, but there's a `rustc_const_unstable` attribute on it:

```
#[rustc_const_unstable(feature = "const_type_id", issue = "77125")]
```

This tells us that the tracking issue for making `TypeId::of` `const`, at least stably so, is [#77125](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/77125). In that issue there's a link to the [PR that reverted its initial stabilization](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/77083), which further links to a [comment by eddyb](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/75923#issuecomment-696676511):

> `TypeId` is one a few types (`mem::Discriminant` is the only other one I can think of) that's a thin wrapper for a private integer, at least right now. This is ripe for abuse *no matter* what we say/document it as.
>
> I'm not saying we should *cater* to this, but rather avoid stabilizing *even worse* abuse-enabling tools like `const fn` `TypeId::of`.
> Like I said, I am already aware of usecases where compile-time `transmute(TypeId::of::<T>())` is an uniquely useful tool and someone might not think twice before releasing a crate which uses it somewhere internally and becomes widely-used.

So it seems the major concern here is the likelihood of unscrupulous code abusing `TypeId::of` to do things at compile time, in a way that makes changing the implementation of `TypeId` difficult to do in the future without major breakage.